# Python imports for module at the same directory level

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following package structure in my python project

```
wolv
   |---car
         |---cos
               |---
                __init__.py
                utils.py
                manager.py
         |---providers
                     |---sl.py
         | **utils.py**
         | config.py
         |__init__.py
```

In `wolv.car.utills.py` I can do `from wolv.car import config` but not `from wolv.car.cos import manager` Any idea why this is happening and how can I import manager in `wolv.car.utills.py`

Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/wvbar-utils", line 6, in <module>
    from wolv.car.utils import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wolv/car/utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    from wolv.car.cos import manager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wolv/car/cos/manager.py", line 10, in <module>
    from wolv.car.cos.providers import sl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wolv/car/cos/providers/sl.py", line 21, in <module>
    from wolv.car import utils
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

manager.py has `from wolv.car.cos.providers import sl` and sl.py has `from wolv.car import utils`

Comment: What specific error are you getting?

Comment: Updated question with more details.

Comment: you can try relative imports

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)